Finding Closed Forms for a System of Recurrence Relations
I am working on a problem that involves a system of recurrence relations with two functions, $A'$ and $A''$. The relations are defined as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
A'_{n,k,m} &= A'_{n-1,k-1,m} + A''_{n-1,k,m-1}, \\
A''_{n,k,m} &= A'_{n-1,k-1,m-1} + A''_{n-1,k,m}.
\end{align*}
$$
The initial conditions for the system are given by:
$$
A'_{0,0,0} = A''_{0,0,0} = 1,
$$
and it is specified that:
$$
A'_{n,k,m} = A''_{n,k,m} = 0 \quad \text{for any} \quad n < 0, \, k < 0, \, \text{or} \, m < 0.
$$
After attempting to solve this via generating functions without success, I reverted to finding closed forms for $A'_{n,k,m}$ and $A''_{n,k,m}$ for specific values of $m$ and guessed a general solution. The solution depends on whether $m$ is even or odd:
For even $m = 2m'$:
$$
\begin{align*}
A'_{n,k,2m'} &= \binom{n-k-1}{m'-1} \binom{k}{m'}, \\
A''_{n,k,2m'} &= \binom{n-k}{m'} \binom{k-1}{m'-1}.
\end{align*}
$$
For odd $m = 2m' + 1$:
$$
\begin{align*}
A'_{n,k,2m'+1} &= \binom{n-k-1}{m'} \binom{k}{m'}, \\
A''_{n,k,2m'+1} &= \binom{n-k}{m'} \binom{k-1}{m'}.
\end{align*}
$$
Despite having these closed forms, I would like to understand how to derive them systematically using generating functions or other formal methods without resorting to guessing.
I appreciate any insights or references to similar problems. Many thanks in advance!

If I may ask though, where did you find this recurrence?

Sure, no secret here! It rises from counting all bit-strings of length $n$ with $k$ ones and $m$ bit flips. That's why it's so similar to binomial coefficients. And it also means that the sum of all these counts for all $m$ equals to a binomial coefficient. $A'$ and $A''$ are the counts if the previous character is 1 or 0.

Oh, that makes sense. Isn't there a much simpler and direct way to derive the formulas then? Like, you just split $k$ zeros and $n-k$ ones in $\lfloor \frac{m+1}{2}\rfloor$ and $\lceil \frac{m+1}{2}\rceil$ non-empty blocks independently.

Yeah, I figured that there should be such combinatorial explanation after I saw the closed form, but I haven't figured it out before that.
I actually have a more interesting problem that I have that I also don't have a combinatorial formula. It is the number of bit strings of length $n$ with $k$ ones, $m$ bit flips and $l$ bit flips of bit flips. I thought that if I have a way to solve this problem fair and square I can solve this other problem.

Let's use $A_{n,k,m}$ and $B_{n,k,m}$.
$$
\begin{cases}
A_{n,k,m} = A_{n-1,k-1,m} + B_{n-1,k,m-1}, \\
B_{n,k,m} = A_{n-1,k-1,m-1} + B_{n-1,k,m}
\end{cases}
$$
If we consider their genfuncs $A(x,y,z)$ and $B(x,y,z)$, the recurrence rewrites into:
$$\begin{cases}
A=xyA+xzB+1, \\
B = xyzA+xB+1
\end{cases}$$
Or, in a matrix form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-xy & xz \\ xyz & 1-x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A \\ B
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This gives the solution:
$$\begin{align}
A = \frac{1+xz-x}{1-x^2yz^2-xy+x^2y-x} & & B = \frac{1+xyz-xy}{1-x^2yz^2-xy+x^2y-x}
\end{align}$$
Note that there is $z^2$, but not $z$ in the denominator.
It is a strong indicator that the sequence may behave differently on odd and even $m$, so it is indeed wise to, instead of two sequences $A$ and $B$, consider four sequences $A_0,A_1,B_0$ and $B_1$ split by the parity of $m$, so that $A(z) = A_0(z^2)+zA_1(z^2)$ and $B(z) = B_0(z^2)+zB_1(z^2)$.
The sequences in question have the following generating functions:
$$\begin{matrix}
A_0 = \frac{1-x}{1-x^2yz-xy+x^2y-x} & A_1 = \frac{x}{1-x^2yz-xy+x^2y-x} \\
B_0=\frac{1-xy}{1-x^2yz-xy+x^2y-x} & B_1 = \frac{xy}{1-x^2yz-xy+x^2y-x}
\end{matrix}$$
Since they all are quite similar in nature, let's actually analyze the single sequence with $1$ in the numerator:
$$
F=\frac{1}{1-x^2yz-xy+x^2y-x}
$$
By definition, it expands into
$$
F=\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty x^s(1+y-xy+xyz)^s
$$
Let's now try to find its coefficient near $x^n y^k z^m$:
$$\begin{align}
[x^n y^k z^m] F &= [x^{n} y^k z^m]\sum\limits_{s} x^s(1+y(1-x+xz))^s\\
&=[x^{n} z^m]\sum\limits_{s} \binom{s}{k}x^s((1-x)+xz)^k \\
&= \binom{k}{m}[x^{n-m}](1-x)^{k-m}\sum\limits_{s} \binom{s}{k}x^s.
\end{align}$$
Note that $\sum\limits_s \binom{s}{k} x^s = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$ is a standard generating function, thus we get
$$
=\binom{k}{m} [x^{n-m}]\frac{x^k(1-x)^{k-m}}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\binom{k}{m} [x^{n-k}]\frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}}
$$
Using the same substitution again, we finally get
$$
\boxed{[x^n y^k z^m] F(x,y,z) =\binom{k}{m} \binom{n-k}{m}}
$$
Specific formulas for $A_0,A_1,B_0$ and $B_1$ trivially follow from this.

Thank you so much for answering!
I have trouble following one step, when you eliminate $y^k$ : $[x^{n} y^k z^m]\sum\limits_{s} x^s(1+y(1-x+xz))^s = [x^{n} y^k z^m]\sum\limits_{s} x^s \sum\limits_{r} \binom{s-r}{r}{y^{r}(1-x+xz)}^{s-r}$ shouldn't the result be $[x^{n} z^m]\sum\limits_{s} \binom{s-k}{k} x^s((1-x)+xz)^{s-k}$?. Then the next binomial coefficient also depends on $s$ and we can't move it out of the sum. It looks like it also the reason why I can't derive my answer for $A_0$, $A_1$, $B_0$ and $B_1$ from yours. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks again!

$(1+y(1-x+xz))^s = \sum\limits_r \binom{s}{r} y^r (1-x+xz)^r 1^{s-r}$ actually, as $y(1-x+xz)$ stand together as $T$ in $(1+T)^s$. Hence we extract $\binom{s}{k} y^k (1-x+xz)^k$ and not $\binom{s}{k} y^k (1-x+xz)^{s-k}$.
$$~$$
Concrete answers for $A_0,A_1,B_0$ and $B_1$ misaligned because I accidentally wrote $\binom{m}{n-k}$ instead of $\binom{n-k}{m}$ when taking $[x^{n-k}] \frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}}$. They should match now, e.g.
$$
[x^n y^k z^m] A_0 = [x^n y^k z^m] (1-x)F=\binom{k}{m}\binom{n-k}{m}-\binom{k}{m}\binom{n-k-1}{m}=\binom{k}{m}\binom{n-k-1}{m-1}
$$
Others are similar.
